# issue with using gem libv8 "3.11.8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the **"gem libv8"** in my Rails project.
So i added

> gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'

in my Gemfile, but when i run **bundle** command, it shows error like below

```
You have requested:

  libv8 ~> 3.11.8

The bundle currently has libv8 locked at 3.3.10.4.

Try running `bundle update libv8`
```

i tried to see what version of libv8 installed in my system by typing **gem list**,
but even in that list it shows like `libv8 (3.11.8.4)`, but not sure why i am getting this error message.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gemfile.lock file is not updated, run *bundle update libv8* and you should be good to go.

Comment: Actually by doing so it showed some other issues related to some other gems. So i deleted the content in Gemfile.lock and it works.